# Silverlight ElevatedTrust for AppsInBrowser works with localhost but not with the machine name url

Tags: silverlight, iis

story short : elevated trust works with : http:// localhost/...
                 but not with : http:// sp2010/...

I created a certificate for a silverlight app to run within the web browser and imported the key to [Trusted Publishers] and everything seems OK when I navigate to the app through [localhost] .. but when I try to access the app through the machine name, It shows that the app is still not trusted.

[demo screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUhjX.png)

Any idea about why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that you have to import the certificate to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
and that's it.